# Getting the ID of the parent DIV

Tags: jquery

I want to get the ID of parent DIV for a specific ID.

This is the HTML:-

```
<div id="sample-name" class="wrapper-dropdown-5" tabindex="2">
     <div class="m2">Heading</div>
         <ul class="dropdown">
             <div class="menu-border">
                   <li class="orange">
                       <a href="#2" data-jumpslide="2" data-goto="diagnostics">
                       ...
                  ...
```

`<a>` is the link which is clicked and when it is clicked, I need the ID (sample-name) for the parent DIV.

This is what I did in the click function of `<a>` :-

```
$(this).parents('div:eq(0)').attr('id').split(' ');
```

but it gives me the following error:-

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Do you think there is any other way or may be I can improve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have duplicate IDs here: sample-name.  Really bad idea!

Comment: To add to @roasted's comment, as per HTML spec, the ID element is constrained to be unique across the entire document. Also, splitting by space is quite out-of-point, an id cannot contain a space in the first place.

Comment: what is the purpose of split?  What is the end return value you want out of this?

Comment: @JosephMarikle is right, you want to split the ID value by spaces, which will never have spaces? what are u looking to get from this?

Comment: Not to split hairs but the parent of your anchor element is a list item, not a div. The div you refer to is an ancestor. Oh and your HTML is invalid.

Comment: I want "sample-name" out of this, which is the ID of the top DIV.

Comment: `$(this).parents("div").filter(function(i) { return $(this).prop("id"); }).first().prop("id")`

Comment: @Faisal then just do this: `$(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');`.  Searches for the first parent with an id and returns the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the class (`wrapper-dropdown-5` on your example) on the parent div you are looking for? Something like this:

```
var parentId =  $(this).parents('div.wrapper-dropdown-5').prop('id') ;
```

Comment: Makes sense, I guess, I was taking the more difficult approach.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put:

```
$(this).parents("div").filter(function(i) { return $(this).prop("id"); }).first().prop("id")
```

- [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

  - Calls all parents of selected element
- [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

  - Reduces a set of matched elements to ones passing method inside
- [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

  - Selects the first in a set of match elements
- [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

  - fetches "properties" of an element

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use `closest`

```
$(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
```

return the id of the closest parent with an id

[Quicky demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cEq6a/)

EDIT: after reviewing it further, I've come to the conclusion that it would be better to use `.parents('[id]')` instead of `closest`. `closest` is inclusive of the active element and it is unlikely that you would want it included.

Comment: dunno what version of jquery he is using. this wont work in older versions

Comment: @SpYk3HH I just use the latest.  If there is a specific version requirement, it should be noted in the question.

Comment: Keep in mind, if looking for a div with id then change param to `'div[id]'`

Answer (score 1):

another aproach:

```
$(this).parents("div.m2").attr("id");
```

or

```
$(this).parents("ul").parent("div").attr("id");
```

Comment: Thanks, the class for each menu changes so this wouldn't be able to suffice. Closest solution in this term would be what Icarus pointed out. Thanks.

Comment: If you always have the same structure, I think my second example can work no matter the menu class